# Connection to own made SQL database in Visual Basic not working

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

I have had a few problems with Visual Studio 2019. I want to make a local database, to then expand on that.

First, I wanted to see if I still could make a simple connection and I failed in doing so (I imported the NuGet package `System.Data.SqlClient` for reference sake).

So what I did so far:

- I created a class `SQLControl` (see the code shown below)
- I also created a simple database with the extension `.mdf`, with a new table called `Food`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Food] 
(
    [Id]        INT           NOT NULL,
    [Food_Name] NVARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
    [Food_Type] NVARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

I populated this data table with 5 ID entries, by editing the "Show Table Data" interface.

After that I wanted to see if the connection worked, so I made a form:

```
public Class Form1
    Private SQL As New SQLControl
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GetFoods()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetFoods()
        SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT Food_Name FROM Food")

        MsgBox(SQL.RecordCount)

    End Sub
End Class
```

This should simply count 5 entries and return with the value of 5 as a popup. But it is only returning me with a 0. Could you guys help me out?

Class SQLControl.vb:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient


Public Class SQLControl

    Private SQLCon As New SqlConnection("Data Source = Database1.mdf;")
    Private SQLCmd As SqlCommand

    Public SQLDA As SqlDataAdapter
    Public SQLDS As DataSet

    Public Params As New List(Of SqlParameter)

    Public RecordCount As Integer
    Public Exception As String
    Public Sub ExecQuery(Query As String)
        Try
            SQLCon.Open()
            SQLCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)

            Params.ForEach(Sub(x) SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(x))

            Params.Clear()

            SQLDS = New DataSet
            SQLDA = New SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
            RecordCount = SQLDA.Fill(SQLDS)

            SQLCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exception = ex.Message
        End Try
        If SQLCon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then SQLCon.Close()
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
        Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
        Params.Add(NewParam)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can't directly open SQL Server `.mdf` files from .NET code like that. The `.mdf` files (and any accompanying `.ndf` and `.ldf` files) have to be hosted and managed by SQL Server, or SQL Server Express, and your code connects through SQL with something like `Server=localhost,1433;Database=Database1;User Id=MySqlLogin;Password=MyStr0ngP4assw0rd;`.

Answer (score 0):

Connection not only need to be closed but also disposed so the connection can be returned to the connection pool. Using ...End Using blocks handle this for you even if there is an error.

Your connection string is not compleat. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-data-sqlclient/
 As you can see, you do not connect to a file with Sql Server. You connect to a database on a server.

Keep your database objects local to the method where they are used so they can be closed and disposed.

Parameters should be added with the .Add method that includes the SqlDbType and Size arguments. It is not reasonable to ask the User Interface code to be aware of these parameters.

Don't return data when all you want is a record count.

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private SQL As New SQLControl
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        GetFoods()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetFoods()
        Dim RecordCount = SQL.GetRecordCount("SELECT Count(Food_Name) FROM Food")
        MsgBox(RecordCount.ToString)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class SQLControl

    Private ConString As String = "Data Source = Database1.mdf;" 'Not a proper connection string

    Public Function GetRecordCount(Query As String) As Integer
        Dim Count As Integer
        Using SQLCon As New SqlConnection(ConString),
                SQLCmd As New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
            SQLCon.Open()
            Count = CInt(SQLCmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
        Return Count
    End Function
End Class
```